# Validating a function in a database

Tags: java, database, list

I'm not sure how to validate this so that if an id value isnt found i can say that the ID value doesn't exist. i have a GUI function with a database in which you enter a id (attribute) of someone and it returns their other information (name, surname, etc) but when an id is not found my program crashes and im not quite sure how to make so that i can use a JOption pane when an id is not found.

```
    int id = Integer.parseInt(jTextField15.getText());
    Person updatePerson = new Person();
    for (Person person : personList)
    {
        if (person.getPersonid() == id)
        {
            updatePerson = person;
        }

        }

    jTextField11.setText(updatePerson.getFirstname());
    jTextField17.setText(updatePerson.getSurname());
    jTextField12.setText(updatePerson.getPersontype());
    jTextField16.setText(updatePerson.getGender());
    jSpinner5.setValue(updatePerson.getDateofbirth());
```

The program seems to work but i am getting an exception in thread message after it cant find the id:

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: illegal value

any help to explain what this is and how to fix it as well as being able print a message to the user would be very appreciated

Comment: What is the problem exactly? How about testing if updatePerson is null or not after the loop?

Comment: You might also want to `break` when the person is found

Comment: using break seems to work but afterwards my program crashes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you mean the following:
what should I do in my GUI when I look up an element and it is not found.

There are 2 approaches you can take:

1: leave out the elements. This works well (usually) for html and other generated user interfaces. After your loop you check if the updatePerson == null, if so, you skip generating the html elements (or text fields, etc)

2: for GUI's you generally use a default value. This can be done in one of 2 ways: you use default values for each field, or you create a dummy object.

```
int id = Integer.parseInt(jTextField15.getText());
Person updatePerson = null;
for (Person person : personList)
{
    if (person.getPersonid() == id)
    {
        updatePerson = person;
        break; // with break: get first found, without break: get last found. 
        // this depends on whether it is possible to have a person show up more than once.
    }
}

if (person == null) {
    jTextField11.setText("");
    jTextField11.setVisible(false); // setting fields to empty, in case logic 
    jTextField17.setText("");       // is using them or if someone
    jTextField17.setVisible(false); // sets visible true before setting text
    jTextField12.setText("");       // as you don't want to output wrong data
    jTextField12.setVisible(false); // even for a flicker of a second
    jTextField16.setText(""); 
    jTextField16.setVisible(false); 
    jSpinner5.setValue(SOME_GLOBAL_DEFAULT_DATE);     // ie. 0 or 1970-01-01 
    jSpinner5.setVisible(false); 
} else {
    jTextField11.setText(updatePerson.getFirstname());
    jTextField17.setText(updatePerson.getSurname());
    jTextField12.setText(updatePerson.getPersontype());
    jTextField16.setText(updatePerson.getGender());
    jSpinner5.setValue(updatePerson.getDateofbirth());
}
```

or you can do (leaving the fields, but empty)

```
int id = Integer.parseInt(jTextField15.getText());
Person updatePerson = new Person(); // default constructor initializes with empty of default values
for (Person person : personList)
{
    if (person.getPersonid() == id)
    {
        updatePerson = person;
        break; // with break: get first found, without break: get last found. 
        // this depends on whether it is possible to have a person show up more than once.
    }
}

jTextField11.setText(updatePerson.getFirstname());
jTextField17.setText(updatePerson.getSurname());
jTextField12.setText(updatePerson.getPersontype());
jTextField16.setText(updatePerson.getGender());
jSpinner5.setValue(updatePerson.getDateofbirth());
```

While writing this I realise I would end up doing a third approach which is related to the first:

```
if (updatePerson == null) {
    panelContainingFields.setVisible(false);
} else {
    jTextField11.setText(updatePerson.getFirstname());
    jTextField17.setText(updatePerson.getSurname());
    jTextField12.setText(updatePerson.getPersontype());
    jTextField16.setText(updatePerson.getGender());
    jSpinner5.setValue(updatePerson.getDateofbirth());
    panelContainingFields.setVisible(true);
}
```

Simply put all the fields you use in a panel, and hide the panel when there's no elements.

Comment: i see, thanks so much. it was the last part i had to do for my project

Comment: even though it works its still giving me an error message at the bottom and also how would i use a JOptionPane to state that the id number doesn't exist

Comment: I strongly urge you to understand the entire code you write, before handing it in. add comment lines at each block that describe to yourself what each part does. this will help you keep track of your code.   I don't think an optionpane itself does that. but you could for instance choose what optionpane to show, based on whether you found a person or not

Comment: ya i was was just a little confused ya im bust commenting my program now thanks for the help